# OSX App Sandbox create directory

Tags: swift, macos, macos-sierra

I have an app that, after saving, creates folder with all screenshots you have made during the usage of the app.

Initially I create them in the documents and if user wants to save project move it where user specifies (`NSSavePanel`). App is sandboxed.

I tried to create dictionary:

```
let dir = (project.directory+"/"+project.name+".screenshots").replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dir)
{
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dir, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error creating directory")
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I am getting error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to
>   save the file “testingProject.screenshots” in the folder “MyProject”."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/namikcatibusic/MyProject/testingProject.screenshots, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000648370 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

I have tried with entitlement keys:

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write   /
```

and

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write: /
```

but got rejected by AppStore. I have standard ones for movies, music and user specified entitlements already.

Any clues what to do? How to create directory for sandboxed app?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying, but what is NSSavePanel for?  Let me suppose that you are trying to save a folder containing a bunch of screenshot files.  If that's the case, then you can't use NSSavePanel.

Comment: I recommend to save the screenshots in a subfolder of the `Documents` folder in the container. Btw: stripping the `file://` scheme from an URL with `replacingOccurrences` is horrible. Use the URL related API to compose the URL and the `path` property to get the path.

Comment: @ElTomato I am using NSSavePanel to determine where to save and create "project" file there (xml).

Comment: @vadian I am trying to save it elsewhere but Documents - is that even possible. Yeah I know that stripping is horrible it is only for testing as much locations as possible.

Comment: Where to save WHAT?  Each screenshot file?  If that's the case, then, again, ask yourself what NSSavePanel is for.  Or save a folder?  You can't use NSSavePanel to save a folder to user-defined path.

Comment: Save file, take location of that file, create folder, create screenshots there